# Check if a file exists in a GRASS mapset

Tags: grass-gis

Is it possible to simply check if a file exists in a GRASS mapset and return FALSE or TRUE?

My task is to process a large file, so I don't want to overwrite it every time, because of resources scarcity. Hence, I would like to check if it already exists.
I tried:

```
eval "g.findfile element=raster file=myfile"
```

and then check with

```
if [ ! "$name" ]; then (also i tried if [ "$name" == "NaN" ] || [ "$name" == "N/A" ]; then)
```

But this eval expression does'n't evaluate any vars. And also this construction is rather complicated. Isn't there a simple way to check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me, using the bash `if [ -z $variable ]; then...` form:

(I have a raster named 'cov')

```
eval `g.findfile element=cell file=cov`
echo $name
cov
if [ -z ${name} ]; then echo "Missing"; fi

# Now a non-existing raster file
eval `g.findfile element=cell file=cov2`
micha@RMS:rOPTRAM$ echo $name
if [ -z ${name} ]; then echo "Missing"; fi
Missing
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
eval "g.findfile element=cell file=rawdem"
echo "DEM - $name"
```
eval is running, but echo doesn't give the name.. although g.findfile writes name=rawdem..

Comment: Yes! It works. I also had  eval "" but I had to change it to eval `` - and now it works.
Micha, thank you a lot, you saved me again with grass gis :)